# Click on a button for another to be clicked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to click on a button (`sbtn2`) so that another is triggered (`sbtn1`). I try:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function() {
        $("#stack").hide();
        $("#sbtn2").on("click", function() {
          $("#sbtn1").click(function() {
            $("#stack").show();
          });
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="sbtn1">OK</button>
    <button id="sbtn2">See</button>
    <p id="stack">
      Hi, my name is Stack Overflow!
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

I would like `stack` to appear only when `sbtn1` is clicked THROUGH `sbtn2`.

That is, I need to press `See` so that it clicks `OK` and `Stack` appears.

Comment: Do you really need the clicking of one button to cause the clicking of another or do you really want the clicking of one button to run the code that the clicking of the second button would have triggered?

Comment: @ScottMarcus your edited snippet is having a problem finding jQuery.

Comment: @Andy No, it's not. Click the second button and then click the first button. It does function, not as the OP wants, but it does function.

Comment: Yup, sorry. Stupid uMatrix was blocking the call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, your code makes it so that when you click on button 2, an event handler for button 1 is set up so that you could then click button 1 and see the hidden message.

To make it so that when button 2 is clicked, it performs the same action that button 1 would do, simply set up a handler on button 2 that calls the button 1 click callback function.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function() {
        $("#stack").hide();
        
        $("#sbtn1").click(function() {
          $("#stack").show();
        });
        
        $("#sbtn2").on("click", function() {
          $("#sbtn1").click();
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="sbtn1">OK</button>
    <button id="sbtn2">See</button>
    <p id="stack">
      Hi, my name is Stack Overflow!
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

Add separate event listeners to both buttons

```
$(function () {

  $("#stack").hide();

  $("#sbtn1").on("click", function () {
    $("#stack").show();
  });

  $("#sbtn2").on("click", function () {
    $("#sbtn1").click();
  });
});
```